# Directshow Virtual Audio Capture Filter, Time Settings

Tags: c++, directshow

I want to implement a Virtual Audio Capture filter.

1- Each audio sample write in Memory Mapped File on another filter graph.

2- In Audio filter, and inside of FillBuffer method Shared Memory read and copy on pSample

3- My problem has shown in the following image:
[image]

While Buffer info duration should be 33ms, it is 1088 ms.

What is wrong? and what I need to change and update?

Thanks for any help or hints.

Comment: I assume that's just the rendering filter (which has its own internal buffer)?

Comment: This is the response from renderer to behavior of your filter. If you are not happy with it, you should check (a) allocator properties, and (b) properties of media samples you are delivering from your filter/pin. If they don't answer your question immediately, you can update here with this additional data.

Comment: Thanks Roman, your recommendation was very helpful. I'm working on it and back very soon with updates.

Comment: rogerpack, No, it is a Virtual Audio Capture filter. and it's buffer filled from another directshow process.

Comment: Thanks again Roman, with your help I could resolve duration delay issue. But another problem is a noise on audio output. are you have any direction for it? Thanks